# How I can display only one object from API array Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

How I can display only one object from [data.hits]? Ive tried map(), filter, also setRecipes([data.hits.recipe[0]]); etc ... and it doesn't work. Currently, it shows 10 objects on the website but I need only one. Thank you for any help.

```
const [recipes,setRecipes] = useState ([]);


useEffect(()=>{
getReciepes();
 },[query]);

const getReciepes = async () => {
const response = await fetch (`https://api.edamam.com/search? 
q=${query}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`);
const data = await response.json();

setRecipes(data.hits);

console.log(data.hits);}
```

Comment: What is the API response format? an array? and is it the first receipt of the response you want to display?

Comment: the Api response is : 10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {recipe: {…}}
1: {recipe: {…}}
2: {recipe: {…}}
3: {recipe: {…}}
4: {recipe: {…}}
5: {recipe: {…}}
6: {recipe: {…}}
7: {recipe: {…}}
8: {recipe: {…}}
9: {recipe: {…}}
length: 10
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Comment: this is a first object:  0:
recipe:
calories: 4228
cautions: ['Sulfites']
cuisineType: ['american']
dietLabels: ['Low-Carb']
digest: (26) []
dishType: ['main course']
healthLabels: (19) []
image: ""
ingredientLines: (10) []
ingredients: (11)[]
label: "Chicken Vesuvio"
mealType: ['lunch/dinner']
source: "Serious Eats"
totalDaily: { …}
totalNutrients: {…}
totalTime: 60
totalWeight: 2976
yield: 4
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: Yes i can return the first object only [0]. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how I did not notice this. Here is a simple solution :

```
  const list=[...data.hits]
  list.length = 1 
  setRecipes(list);

  console.log(list);
}
```